# How to find a string that starts with a certain pattern in python?

Tags: python, string

New to Python.

A really simple question, but I did a lot of research and didn't find the answer:

I need to find all strings that start with 'df-' in python, which method should I call please?

Thanks

Comment: `string.startswith('df-')`. You literally answered your own question

Comment: thanks both for the quick response!! :)

Comment: Or you can use regex `re.search("^df-.*",MyString)`